# How to target merged cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, merge, target

this is the code I've gotten to so far. It allows for all cells in range to pop out in a `UserForm` along with the cell values. But it doesn't work for merged cells.  The duplicate code is there since there's a limit to the `Range`.
I have no idea what to add to make merged cells to pop out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D42:D46,D52,D56,D60,D71,E42:E45,E56,E127,F17,F18,F55,F71,G16,G20,G25,G27,G33,G36,G42:G45,G47,G51:G54,G56,G58,G65:G67,G74,G75,G78,G84,G108,G110,G114,G119,G125,G128,G129,G131,G138,G139,G152,G156,G168,G169,G172,G180:G184,G187:G191,H16,H55,H60,H75,H78,H119,J8")) Is Nothing Then
 UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = Target.Value
 UserForm1.Show
End If
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J17,J20,J42,J60,J65,J66,J75,J77,J78,L88")) Is Nothing Then
 UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = Target.Value
 UserForm1.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: when you select merged cells, `Target.Cells.Count` is greater than 1. You probably need to check `If Target.MergeCells` first to handle the possibility of merged cells.

Comment: Alternately, you can work with `Target.MergeArea.Cells(1)`.

Comment: I believe `Target.Cells(1).Value` will get you the value both for merged cells and regular cells.

Comment: Something like this? (I probably should have mentioned that I'm a complete beginner at this)
```If Target.Cells(1).Value = "$J$88:$L$88" Then
 UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = Target.Value
 UserForm1.Show```

Comment: You would change `If Not Intersect(Target` to `If Not Intersect(Target.Cells(1)...`, and also get rid of `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`